# What is the difference between java.util.ArrayList and java.sql.Array

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, package

There are two package containing the same implementation of collections. One in java.util package of jdk and another in java.sql package of hibernate.

So, I want to know what is the difference between collections classes in java.util package and java.sql package.

```
Eg. java.util.ArrayList and java.sql.Array classes.
```

Do anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? `java.sql.ArrayList` does not exist in [JRE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: java.util.ArrayList exists, java.sql.ArrayList does not

Comment: Sorry I am talking about Array class. I corrected it.

Comment: `java.sql` is part of the JRE, not part of Hibernate, and it doesn't contain any implementations at all, just interfaces and abstract classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most of the classes under "java.sql" package I believe, are interfaces to which the JDBC drivers provide specific implementation. The classes in the "java.sql" package provide wrappers to code against without knowing the specific implementation.
To know exactly how java.sql.Array is implemented you would have to know the particular JDBC driver's implementation/code.
As "tbodt" has mentioned, it is to handle a particular SQL data type coming back. Not all drivers support this type, check out the following link to see how it might be used,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html

java.util.ArrayList is an actual implementation of the "Collection" interface. Some of the Other implementation of the Collection are LinkedList,Vector etc

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what Jeffery is saying, there is no `java.sql.ArrayList` class. If you meant `java.sql.Array` (there is such a class), the difference is that `Array` is used to retrieve SQL arrays from a datastore, and `ArrayList` is used as an all-purpose way to have a collection of objects.

Comment: Yes you are correct it is Array class. But is there any difference in it's implementation.

Comment: The classes are completely different. `Array` simply asks an SQL database for an object of the SQL type `ARRAY`. It does not coordinate the actual storage of array elements. `ArrayList` actually stores the elements in it's own data storage facilities.